# Why everything in RStudio workspace vanishes every time I close it?

Tags: r, rstudio, workspace

Every time I close and open the RStudio, everything in the panels including all the data frames, functions, values, etc. vanishes and some very old ones that I have deleted long ago appears. I save workspace when I want to close it, but this happens every time. Importing my large dataset and generating everything again every time takes a lot of time. What can I do?

Comment: Above the *Environment* pane there is a small `Open` icon left to the `Save` icon. You also might want to switch off automatic loading of old workspaces in the RStudio options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your workspace and restore it under Tools -> Options -> General. 
Please see picture below.

[image]

In addition you can also use:

```
save.image(file='Session.RData')
```

And load it later:

```
load('Session.RData')
```

However, generally speaking, some consider it bad to keep/save your environment/workspace.